# A lot of warnings with cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-2.x

Hello I am new to cocos2d-x v3 and I have started with hello world app as well. But when I run the Xcode there are 263 warnings. is it normal ? should I try to fix them or I made a mistake ? or are those warnings harmless ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are some warnings. You shoudn't really worry about them, but make sure you're using the latest version.

Comment: thx a lot. I want to make a mmorpg 2d game do you know any tutorial about that or how can I make myself better to make that kind of online games for iOS android ? @Makalele

Comment: For cocos2d-x tutorials check out Sonar Systems on youtube, for general help check out http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org. However I don't have any experience with online games so I can't help in that matter. Anyway today I've created a new project with cocos studio (cocos2d-x 3.8.1) and I have only 1 warning (update to recommended settings), but it's most probably because cocos lib is precompiled so ofc it's not checked for any warnings or errors (it's only linked to rest of game).